# pip install on Mac OS X - PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, unix, environment-variables, pip

I am trying to install pip on my OS X 10.9.4 machine. I've had problems with different versions of python in the past but I think I've fixed these issues by deleting the corresponding files.

This is what I get when I try `sudo easy_install pip`:

```
╭─ishaantaylor@Ishaans-MacBook-Pro.local ~
╰─➤  sudo easy_install pip                                                                       1 ↵
Password:
TEST FAILED: /lib/python2.7/site-packages/ does NOT support .pth files
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /lib/python2.7/site-packages/

and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

    ''

Here are some of your options for correcting the problem:

* You can choose a different installation directory, i.e., one that is
  on PYTHONPATH or supports .pth files

* You can add the installation directory to the PYTHONPATH environment
  variable.  (It must then also be on PYTHONPATH whenever you run
  Python and want to use the package(s) you are installing.)

* You can set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files by
  using one of the approaches described here:

  http://peak.telecommunity.com/EasyInstall.html#custom-installation-locations

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

And then I added `export PYTHONPATH="/lib/python2.7/site-packages/"` to my ~/.zprofile (I'm using zsh).

I `source ~/.zprofile` and deleted the corrupted pip from my system and tried `sudo easy_install pip` again and I got the exact same error.

Could somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong, and what to do to fix it? Also could anybody recommend any resources that I could read to better understand the way these things work?

Comment: You added the path to YOUR profile, but sudo won't have those environment variables. `sudo env` and see if PYTHONPATH is defined, if it's not, you'll have to get it defined and set to appropriate values. Is your python actually installed into /lib/python2.7? That's not the system provided python path (/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages) nor the path used by brew (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages), how did you install this python version?

Comment: @ssnobody I have the system default (I believe) and the python.org installers. I tried to delete everything but the system default..did I delete the wrong version? Also, where is the python executable for the system provided, default python?

Comment: I have one at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` What do you mean by 'I tried to delete everything except the system default'? What exactly did you do? Also, what is your current $PATH?